# If statement not working, but kinda working

Tags: php, file-io, if-statement

I made a php script to see if what the contents of a txt file are the same as the users input.   I wrote an if statement to see if it is correct and if it isn't send it to an else.  If i dont send any variables, then it works, and displays

`a is b is file is 1`

but if i enter the file and the correct contents it displays

`a is test.txt b is hello file is hello 0`

Here is my code

```
<?php
session_destroy();
$a=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['a']);
$b=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['b']);
$my_file = file_get_contents($a);
echo "a is $a\n";
echo "b is $b\n";
echo "file is $my_file\n";
if ( $my_file == $b ) {
echo "1";
}else {
echo "0";
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any white space (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) in the file?

Comment: try the condition (trim($my_file) == $b)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!  I tried (trim($my_file) == $b) and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are un-initialized variables, so if you enter nothing, then you're getting if (false == false) which is true.

This is because php interprets null as being false. It's weird, I acknowledge.

Either check to see if your variables have been set, or initialize them with defaults.

Comment: You misunderstand. AIUI, the code works correctly when the OP "does not send any variables." The problem occurs when the variables _are_ initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try using htmlspecialchars function on the content you read from your file as well just to be on the safe side, then use trim on the input you read from a file and on the user input as well